# Import arquivos CSS com SASS

Tags: css, sass

Sou iniciando em SASS e estou tentando fazer um arquivo CSS que será um combinado de diversos plug-ins que estão em formato .css (bootstrap, fontawesome, etc) e para isso estou utilizando o SASS, porém não está funcionando neste caso, ele está me retornando a mesma coisa, com os imports e tudo mais só que na sintaxe css ao invés de me retornar uma versão minificada de todos os plug-ins.. sabem me dizem pq?

Segue me arquivo que irá gerar o .css (uso formato .sass):

```
/*===PLUGINS */
@import '../assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
@import '../assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css'
@import '../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'

/*===FONTES */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700)
```

E está é a linha de comando que está compilando:

```
sass --watch --no-cache --sourcemap=none sass\globalMandatories.sass:assets\global\css\globalMandatories.min.css --style compressed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque os arquivos .css não possuem a sintaxe de um arquivo .sass/.scss, a melhor alternativa pra fazer o que você quer, é usar um **task runner** como **GULP (recomendo)** ou **GRUNT**

**[GULP SASS CONCAT/MINIFY](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass)**

Comment: Ótimo! Obrigado @Vinicius